# put values to dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to put the data extracted from a dictionary into another dictionary. I want tu put what I got from that loop into list_od_id = []

```
for item in album['tracks']['data']:
    print(item['id'])

list_of_id = []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in album['tracks']['data']:
    list_of_id.append(item['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a certain value to a list use:

```
yourList.append(yourValue)
```

For your Code that would be:

```
list_of_id =[]
for item in album['tracks']['data']:
    list_of_id.append(item['id'])
print(list_of_id)
```

EDIT
As it seems you confused a list with a dictionary.
your `list_of_id` is has the datatype list.
That means it is a Set of values.

A dictionary on the over hand Looks Like this:

```
myDictionary= {"Key": "value"}
```

Here you have one value for one Key.

Answer (score 0):

So What I think your trying to say is you want the data of the dictionary to be put in a list.

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1:

```
dict = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
values = []
for i in dict:
    values.append(dict[i])
print("values: " + values)
```

2:

```
dict = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
values = []
for key, value in dict.items():
    values.append(value)
    print(key + ": " + value)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

quick solution for create new list of item['id'].

```py
list_of_id = [item['id'] for item in album['tracks']['data']]
```